Not able to deploy the serverless on Azure
I have set up a serverless application that needs to be deployed on Azure. I have completed all the setup mentioned in the documentation. Whenever I am trying to run sls deploy. It is giving:
Error: The client 'aa875774-ab8a-41e7-a567-0a4f0bc7cedc' with object id 'aa875774-ab8a-41e7-a567-0a4f0bc7cedc' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups/write' over scope '/subscriptions/SUBID/resourcegroups/sls-weur-dev-zucora-apps-rg' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.
    at new RestError (/Users/raman/Documents/project/node_modules/@azure/ms-rest-js/dist/msRest.node.js:1403:28)
    at /Users/raman/Documents/project/node_modules/@azure/ms-rest-js/dist/msRest.node.js:2592:37
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)


I have tried adding the roles and permissions. The user that I am using is the admin user and has all the read and write permissions. But still getting the same error when deploying.
I am not able to see where to add RBAC in my permissions as mentioned here.
This deployment only contains functions.
The below image contains the screenshot for the IAM Access Control for the subscription. The user has both Owner and Contributor roles.

The below Screenshot contains the serverless.yml

I then created a new account and followed all the steps for a new account, and I am still getting the same error.

I got the same error when I tried to deploy the serverless azure function using sls deploy:

To resolve this error, you should assign Contributor role to the User in the Subscription.


Updated Subscription ID in Serverless.yml:

provider:
  name: azure
  region: West US 2
  runtime: nodejs12
  # os: windows  # windows is default, linux is available
  # prefix: "sample"  # prefix of generated resource name
  subscriptionId: <Subscription_ID>


I could deploy the Serverless app to Azure:

C:\Users\uname\slsapp>sls deploy
Running "serverless" from node_modules
Initializing provider configuration...
Warning: You're relying on provider "azure" defined by a plugin which doesn't provide a validation schema for its config.
Please report the issue at its bug tracker linking: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/plugins#extending-validation-schema
You may turn off this message with "configValidationMode: off" setting

Removing .serverless directory
Parsing Azure Functions Bindings.json...
Parsing Azure Functions Bindings.json...
Building binding for function: hello event: httpTrigger
Building binding for function: goodbye event: httpTrigger
Logging into Azure
Using subscription ID: <subscription_id>
Creating resource group: sls-wus2-dev-slsapp-rg
Creating function app: sls-wus2-dev-slsapp
-> Creating ARM template from type: consumption
-> Merging environment configuration
Listing deployments for resource group 'sls-wus2-dev-slsapp-rg':
-> Deploying ARM template...
---> Resource Group: sls-wus2-dev-slsapp-rg
---> Deployment Name: slswus2devslsapp-DEPLOYMENT-t1716290176855
-> ARM deployment complete
Deploying serverless functions...
Deploying zip file to function app: sls-wus2-dev-slsapp
-> Deploying service package @ C:\Users\uname\slsapp\.serverless\slsapp.zip
Publishing to URI: https://sls-wus2-dev-slsapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy
Uploading file at 'C:\Users\uname\slsapp\.serverless\slsapp.zip' to container 'deployment-artifacts' with name 'slswus2devslsapp-ARTIFACT-t1716290176855.zip'
Finished uploading blob
-> Function package uploaded successfully
Deployed serverless functions:
-> goodbye: [GET] sls-wus2-dev-slsapp.azurewebsites.net/api/goodbye
-> hello: [GET] sls-wus2-dev-slsapp.azurewebsites.net/api/hello

Portal:

Hello function:

Goodbye function:


Hello Pravallika KV, I have already performed these steps, and still getting the same error. I have updated the question and added the screenshot for the IAM access control for the subscription.

Did you update the subscription id in serverless.yml?

Yes, I have updated the subscriptionId: <> in provider in serverless.yml.

Check if the subscription id in the error and the id you have provided in serverless.yml are same.

Yes they are same.

I have also added the serverless.yml screenshot in the question.

Run the commands az login and az account set --subscription <subscription_id>, then install serverless and perform all the steps again.

Install serverless as in using npm and pip?

Install using npm.

I have logged in again and set the subID again and then installed the serverless. I am still getting exactly the same error. Should I create a new subscription? if that's going to help. Right now Pay-as-you-go is selected in the subscription.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

After weeks of Research and hit and try, I have found a solution which worked for me.
After following all the steps mentioned in the question, I had to assign the contributor role using the azure cli.
As Azure RBAC (role-based access control) has these scopes in order -
Management group -> Subscription -> Resource group -> Resources.
I assigned the role using:
az ad sp create-for-rbac --name "alchemy-serverless" --role contributor --scopes /subscriptions/<SUBID> --sdk-auth

And After that I exported all IDs and secrets form here:
$ export AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID='<subscriptionId>'
$ export AZURE_TENANT_ID='<tenantId>'
$ export AZURE_CLIENT_ID='<servicePrincipalId>'
$ export AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET='<password>'

After that things started to work for me.
